# Reply Keyboard Markup

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

i want to make bot with reply message after pressing specific button of my buttons what do i do ?
for example i have buttons like :
keyboard = ['setting' , 'example' , 'about us']
and i want send message ('this is an example') after pressing example button and send message ('we are your friends ') after about us button what do i do ? i dont want inline keyboards at this step

```
def start(bot , update):
    chat_id2 = update.message.chat_id
    keyboard = ['setting' , 'example' , 'about us']
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id2 , 'choose on of these keyboards' , 
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard , resize_keyboard = True , one_time_keyboard = True))
```

what do i do after this when for example user press example button and i wand send message to user 'this is example ' and show message ' we are your friends' after pressing about us button

Comment: Hi, I'm with the same problem and would be awesome to know if you could achieve that